# DynamoDB simple scan - getting 0 results

Tags: python, boto3

I'm using DynamoDB through Python (Boto3), trying to perform a simple table scan but keep getting 0 results.
When I'm trying to use the same scan filter on AWS console, it returns the correct # of results..

my request code:

```
response = table.scan(
            FilterExpression=Attr('datetime').eq(1453630770)
        )
```

Note: the "datetime" attribute is a number type

Note2: table scan without params yielded results correctly

What did I do wrong? Thanks duders

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the answer - apparently I've reached the max response size (large objects) and fixed it by iterating DynamoDB table using 'LastEvaluatedKey'

A few rounds of scans yielded all results properly.

```
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(
            ProjectionExpression=pe,
            FilterExpression=fe,
            ExpressionAttributeNames= ean,
            ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
            )
```

More info here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html

Hope someone will find it helpful.